# send path to application with shell context menu

Tags: .net

I like to send an path to my application with shell context menu.

I use the following shell context menu which send this command prompt "C:\loger.exe"/clog which runs the app only to my app. How to send the selected path instead of only running the app.

ps Im using .net2

thank you

"C:\loger.exe"/clog

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> c:\logger.exe /clog "%1"

The %1 is the place holder for the selected file, double quotes to ensure that path names with spaces don't cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the command as:

```
"C:\loger.exe" "%1" /clog
```